# how could I get default sms app's package name?

Tags: android, sms

As default sms app is added in 4.4, I cannot open default sms app like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(intent);
```

So how could I get default sms app's package name, so I can open it from my app directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

//http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/provider/Settings.java#Settings.Secure.0SMS_DEFAULT_APPLICATION

public static final String SMS_DEFAULT_APPLICATION = "sms_default_application";

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/SmsApplication.java#267

```
if(Utils.hasKikKat()) {
    String defaultApplication = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),  SMS_DEFAULT_APPLICATION);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(defaultApplication );
      if (intent != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
      }
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I think in the above code. Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName); should be changed to Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(defaultApplication);

Comment: well done!   "sms_default_application" is a great finding. Thank you

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer did not work for me (and seems rather unreliable).

A better way to get the package name is

```
Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
```

This requires API 19+

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you do it:

```
@Nullable
public static String getDefaultSmsAppPackageName(@NonNull final Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        try {
            return Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
        } catch (final Throwable e) {
        }
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT).setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (!resolveInfoList.isEmpty())
        return resolveInfoList.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;
    return null;
}
```